# Use of "en" in this sentence

Tags: choix-de-mot, en

Il dit à son frère qu’il partait pour en apprendre davantage au sujet de la vie et lui demanda de veiller sur sa famille pour lui.

Answer (score 1):

I venture to suggest that the pronoun "en" here is related to an omitted noun.
There is a phrase [apprendre les choses de la vie](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/french-english/apprendre-les-choses-de-la-vie) where you can notice a noun "choses". In your sentence, however, it is omitted. When you omit a noun in such a way, you should use "en". For example:

- J’achète des pommes = j’en achète.
- J’ai deux enfants = j’en ai deux.

Hope it helped.

Comment: Generally, *en* can only replaces noun phrases of the form *de ...*, like *des pommes* in *j'achète des pommes*, and *deux d'enfants* in *j'en ai deux.* So it's not replacing *choses*.